# Opening CSS only model popup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to call the following HTML div using jquery or javascript,
using the following scripts:

```
 $("#open-modal").modal("toggle");
 $("#open-modal").modal("show"); 
 $("#open-modal").modal("hide");
 $("#open-modal").toggle();
 $("#open-modal").show();
 $("#open-modal").hide();
```

I am able to open the popup using the button. Here is the HTML code

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="interior">
    <a class="btn" href="#open-modal">CSS-Only Modal</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close">Close</a>
    <h1>Success!</h1>
    <div>PoP up Me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The full code is in [JS fiddle](https://codepen.io/timothylong/pen/HhAer/)

Comment: its not an bootstrap modal so your js code is not working

Comment: Can i share something other which works for the same thing ?

Comment: This will show modal window `window.location.href = "#open-modal"` for your problem.
You are not using bootstrap modal so all those jquery lines will not work.

Comment: As in the topic,this is a pure css model ,and not a bootstrap model.we would like to open it automatically inside **<script>**  tags on onload section.

Comment: @RaghulRamkish then just add `window.location.href = "#open-modal` this line inside `<script>` it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the script @WaseemAnsar , "window.location.href = "#open-modal" is also working in JS .This is the solution i am currently using,Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not using bootstrap modal and hence you cannot use `modal` calls.

See below example of bootstrap modal

```js
$(function(){
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#open-modal').modal('show');
  });
})
```

```css
.modal-window {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  &>div {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 2em;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  header {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 150%;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
  }
}

.modal-close {
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
    color: black;
  }
}

/* Demo Styles */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 600 18px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#7f53ac 0,#657ced 100%);
  color: black
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.modal-window div:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

small {
  color: #aaa;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  i {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="interior">
    <a class="btn" href="#"> Basic CSS-Only Modal</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="open-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Voilà!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>A CSS-only modal based on the :target pseudo-class. Hope you find it helpful.</p>
          <div><small>Check out</small></div>
    <a href="https://aminoeditor.com" target="_blank"> Amino: Live CSS Editor for Chrome</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i used your snippet and added on load function too. nice way of doing.

Comment: happy to help you :)